# Syncfusion Xamarin ListView , problem with rightswipe

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Can I ask a little help?

I used a SfListView Control, and the ListView works, but the right swiping is not work.
I read the documentation on Syncfusion's site, but I can't find the solution.

Thanks the answers!

```
        <sflistview:SfListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource greybackground}" ItemSpacing="15"  Orientation="Vertical" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}" AllowSwiping="True" SelectionMode="Single" >
      <sflistview:SfListView.RightSwipeTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="0">
              <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       HeightRequest="50"
                       WidthRequest="50"
                       Source="animalsafety.png"/>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </sflistview:SfListView.RightSwipeTemplate>
      <sflistview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="24*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="92*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label BackgroundColor="Orange" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <border:SfBorder Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BorderColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="30" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource headercolor}">
              <Image Source="{Binding IJob.CategoryImageWhite}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource headercolor}"/>
            </border:SfBorder>

              <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding IJob.Company}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
              <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding IJob.Job}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            <border:SfBorder Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="{Binding StatusColor}" CornerRadius="30" BorderColor="Transparent">
              <Button BackgroundColor="{Binding StatusColor}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding ICommandJobStatus}" Clicked="JobStatusClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </border:SfBorder>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </sflistview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>

    </sflistview:SfListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you perform swiping on button or any other interaction control inside SfListView, the touch is handled by the interaction control itself and will not swipe the ListView. In order to perform swiping even on interaction control we suggest you to set **InputTransparent=”True”** like in the following code snippet,

```
<Button BackgroundColor="{Binding StatusColor}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Command="{Binding ICommandJobStatus}" Clicked="JobStatusClicked" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Center"
        InputTransparent="True"/>
```

Please find the following video sample for your reference,

Video Link : [Video](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SfListViewRightSwipeTemplate-1123861168.zip)